# Easy and efficient language for cross platform parallel port interfacing

Tags: windows, linux, parallel-port

I want to use parallel port (LPT) to receive and send data, i have done that before in various language in different OS, like VB in windows, C in linux.

But now, i want to use a language (and a library for LPT access i guess) which is cross platform. So that i can write code in linux and can compile that on my father's windows without changing the code.

The java comm api would be a great choice but official api doesn't support windows and rxtx is 2 years old.

So which language and library will be easier and efficient, i mean, easy to bundle, easy to install etc... and i need linux and windows compatibly.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel port i/o has no standard portable interface.  On MSDOS, Windows, and Linux, significantly different paradigms and APIs are used.

The best you can do is write an application which uses an abstract API and then provide that API on each of the target platforms.  There are probably already libraries available which does the lower part, but I don't know of any offhand.